Refactoring the application with correct SemVer approach
Suppose I have an application with version 1.2.3.
If I refactor my application to remove deprecated calls while maintaining the same functionality and API as in version 1.2.3, what version number should I assign to the new release according to Semantic Versioning (SemVer) rules?

This isn't clear. Is the "deprecated calls" something internal? Because if you deprecated a part of your API in v1.2.3 and then removed it in a future version, it's not possible to have "the same functionality and API" - the deprecated functionality or parts of the interface would be gone.

My assumption was these deprecated calls were public, otherwise SemVer doesn't really apply. But that also assumes the OP knows that SemVer doesn't apply to internal members of a library or module. Rafael, can you clarify what you mean by "deprecated calls?" The visibility of those calls to outside code is the driving force behind any answer to this question.

@GregBurghardt If the calls are part of the API (which conflicts with the fact that there is "the same functionality and API"), then Philip is right and it's a major version increase. However, SemVer addresses what to do when you update your own dependencies.

I mean that I refactor deprecated calls to external dependencies and rework parts of code that use these deprecated calls. It is important to note that the public API will remain intact as I stated in my question.

By definition “refactoring” doednt change the externally visible behaviour.

I agree with Philip Kendall's answer, on the supposition that you've removed a public method or altered public behavior which had previously been marked as deprecated.
The short answer here is that the main focus on a major version increase is on breaking public behavior. Whether or not that public behavior had previously been marked as deprecated is irrelevant.
If your change adds to or extends the public behavior, without having any impact on what had already been publically available in the previous version, then you're not forced to upgrade your major version (but you're still allowed to, e.g. if you're adding a massive new feature).
If you've removed a previously deprecated internal method, that's not really relevant in terms of versioning, other than the fact that making any kind of changes always requires a rebuild, which in turn will always entail some kind of version update (in the lower digits).

As I noted in my question the behavior of the application and public API remain the same. There are no breaking changes at all. From end-user's perspective it will be the same app, but internally I will refactor all deprecated calls to external dependencies.

@Rafael: It was originally ambiguous whether you were discounting deprecated public methods as no longer counting towards the application's (non-deprecated) public behavior. You didn't outright state it, but both me and Philip Kendall interpreted it as a possible interpretation of your phrasing. My answer covers both interpretations and how it impacts whether you should or shouldn't be forced to upgrade major versions.

Version 2.0.0.
Removing something, even something deprecated, is a breaking change.

I'm not sure that this answer answers the question. I think the "deprecated calls" are calls to internal libraries or dependencies being removed. Although maybe the wording is confusing, I don't see how you could deprecate and then later remove part of the interface while "maintaining the same ... API". If you had a particular API call that was part of your public interface, removing it would no longer be maintaining the same API, which would make this correct and the question worded wrongly.

I don't disagree with your analysis. I'll leave this answer up for now pending clarification from the querent.

As I noted in my question the behavior of the application and public API remain the same. There are no breaking changes at all. From end-user's perspective it will be the same app, but internally I will refactor all deprecated calls to external dependencies.

Would be nice to support that with a link to https://semver.org/

By definition, refactoring cannot change the externally visible behavior. Therefore, the possible version numbers are 1.2.4, 1.3.0, or 2.0.0, but the latter two would be unusual and might confuse consumers.
Remember the (simplified) rules for semantic versioning:

If you break externally visible, documented behavior, you must increase the major version.
If you add externally visible, documented behavior, you must increase the minor version.
If you change anything at all, you must increase the patch version.
If you change any of the major or minor version, all following parts are reset to 0.

Note that it doesn't explicitly say you are not allowed to change the major or minor version if there are no changes to the externally visible, documented behavior. However, doing so would be unusual.
There is an argument to be made that increasing the major version without also breaking compatibility is not allowed: the rules for the minor version state [bold italic emphasis mine]

Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backward compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. It MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated. It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements are introduced within the private code. It MAY include patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.

The fact that the rules for the minor version explicitly specify an optional exception ("MAY"), whereas the rules for the major version do not explicitly contain such an exception, could be interpreted as disallowing increasing the major version without a breaking change.
So, depending on how you interpret the document, either

1.2.4 and 1.3.0 are allowed, the latter only if you consider the refactoring a "substantial improvement", or
1.2.4, 1.3.0, and 2.0.0 are allowed.

However, anything except 1.2.4 would be unusual, confusing, and – most importantly – not useful. Remember the goals of semantic versioning: it should be programmatically possible to determine whether it is safe to upgrade dependencies. It should be possible to judge the risk level of upgrading dependencies. By increasing the version number to 1.3.0 or even 2.0.0 you signal a level of risk that does not exist.
If you feel that you want to communicate a significant achievement, you should rather think about separating the technical and the marketing version number. You can increase your technical version number from 1.2.3 to 1.2.4, to let all downstream consumers know that it is safe to upgrade, and you can increase your marketing version number from "2000" to "XP" (ahem) to tell your customers you made some great changes that will totally improve their lives and they should give you all their monies.

If you are removing something this is API change. API changes are major. Let me quote the source (emphasize added):

How should I handle deprecating functionality?
Deprecating existing functionality is a normal part of software development and is often required to make forward progress. When you deprecate part of your public API, you should do two things: (1) update your documentation to let users know about the change, (2) issue a new minor release with the deprecation in place. Before you completely remove the functionality in a new major release there should be at least one minor release that contains the deprecation so that users can smoothly transition to the new API.

